# Copy and pasting with CTRL + C and CTRL + V from one scene to another isn't working!

Tags: edit-mode

I have 2 scenes in blender, i'm making a game in the blender game engine. For some weird reason when I try to copy and object with CTRL + C and then paste it into another scene by pressing CTRL + V, instead of it pasting the copied object into the scene that I want it to be pasted it in, it just creates a copy of the scene I copied the object from,  I don't get it, it doesn't make sense, I know I can just press CTRL + L and link the selected objects into the other scene, but then they always match the same location of which scene they are currently active in, I want to just be able to select an object, press CTRL + C and then switch to the scene I want to paste it in, then press CTRL + V, and the object I copied just simply gets pasted into the scene. Please help if you have a solution to this. Thank you.

Comment: Does it work as expected if you open default blender,  copy cube (ctrl-C), add a new scene, paste cube (Ctrl-V) ?

Comment: nope, it does not work when I try that.

Answer (score 1):

This phenomena could be caused by having to less RAM memory present on your computer,(since all data from one blender project needs to be  in RAM memory, before it can be   into the 2nd Blender again.

Here are a few solutions:
1 - Close down *every other* applications you do not use at that moment and then do the copy-and-paste operation again. See how that works.

2 - Copy and Paste *object by object* instead of everything at once

3 - *Export* all needed objects (to hard-disk) and then *import* them again from the 2nd blender application

4 - If all fails, re-create the object in the 2nd scene.

Comment: Your welcome Hexadecimal